# Cannot find shared library while compiling C program with -static

Tags: c, shared-libraries

#### demo.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void shared_call()
{

 printf("fun call \r\n"); 

}
```

#### demo_main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

   shared_call()

}
```

```
gcc -shared -fpic -o libdemo.so demo.c

gcc demo_main.c -L. -ldemo
```

This compiles correctly, but when I try this:

```
gcc -static  demo_main.c -L. -ldemo
```

It gives me the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldemo
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why does it give me this error when I compile with `-static`?

Comment: Your `demo_main.c` looks very broken -- if you don't add the *correct* declaration of `shared_call`, you will almost surely get yourself in trouble. Always compile with all warnings and ignore none of them!

Answer (score 2):

You need a *static* library for static linking, with expected name `libdemo.a`. Make it like this:

```
gcc -c -o demo.o demo.c
ar rcs libdemo.a demo.o
```

Comment: my question is why this give me error if i use standard library -lm (math) then work ok them why i create shared library give me error what wrong i do in own create lib

Comment: @nitinrakh: `libm` probably does ship with a static version, while your own library doesn't.

Comment: ok if nm /lib64/libm.so.6 |grep init then why show                    0000003459443e38 t _fini                               0000003459403d88 t _init  if it is static version

Comment: @nitinrakh `libm.so.6` is the shared version, there's very probably a `libm.a` in your /lib64 too, and `gcc -static foo.c -lm` links with that.

Comment: @nitinrakh: I have no idea what you just asked -- the static library is in `/usr/lib/libm.a` on my machine.